# What is the correct alternate for innerHTML in angular

Tags: angular, angular8

In my angular application, I use the tooltip. when user hover to element I change the tip value. at present I use the `innerHTML` and updating. works well.

from the security team, they are asking me to avoid the `innerHTML` being used. so what is the alternate for this?

any one advice me the right way?
Thanks in advance.

directive code :

```
   showToolTip() {
        this.container = this.renderer.createElement('div');
        this.container.setAttribute('class', `ibo-tooltip ${this.ToolTip.class}`);
        this.container.setAttribute('id', `${this.ToolTip.id}`);
        this.container.innerHTML = `<div>${this.ToolTip.info}</div>`;

        return this.container;

    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code, as it's hard to tell why you would be using `innerHTML` in the first place at the moment

Comment: Consider using dynamic components, even I have used the same for tooltip

Comment: @prabhatojha - can you share me sample / tutorial please?

Comment: @Kurt Hamilton  - I am using directive. from the HostListener i am getting the arrtribute value and generating the new value in popup.

Comment: OK, any chance of a demo?

Comment: @KurtHamilton - let me share my directive code

Comment: @KurtHamilton - my directive code snippet added for your reference

Comment: @3gwebtrain I will share the same in some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do is to have a toggle variable that says if you want to show the tooltip or not

`this.container.innerHTML =`${this.ToolTip.info}`;` this will really cause security issues, but this solution [innerHTML]="Tooltip.info" will not and angular sanitizes the html string in this case, its not equals to `element.innerHTML`.
https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example please read this, under security and uses `innerHTML` property binding

```
<-- Template -->
<ng-container *ngIf="isTooltipShow">
   <div class="ibo-tooltip {{Tooltip.class}}" [id]="Tooltip.id" [innerHTML]="Tooltip.info">
   </div>
</ng-container>

//Typescript
 isTooltipShow: boolean;

 showTooltip() {
     this.isTooltipShow = true;
 }
```

If `Tooltip.info` doesn't contains any html strings, you can go for this solution

```
<-- Template -->
<ng-container *ngIf="isTooltipShow">
   <div class="ibo-tooltip {{Tooltip.class}}" [id]="Tooltip.id">
      {{ Tooltip.info }}
   </div>
</ng-container>

//Typescript
 isTooltipShow: boolean;

 showTooltip() {
     this.isTooltipShow = true;
 }
```

Comment: I am looking a solution to avoid `innerHTML`

Comment: `this.container.innerHTML = `<div>${this.ToolTip.info}</div>`;` this will really cause security issues, but this solution [innerHTML]="Tooltip.info" will not and angular sanitizes the html string in this case, its not equals to `element.innerHTML`.


https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example please read this, under security and uses `innerHTML` property binding

Comment: I have updated my answer @3gwebtrain, please check :) and just present the link I have sent you to your security team, since angular knows such issue and prevent's it if you use attribute binding via `[innerHTML]` not `element.innerHTML`

Comment: No problem, Goodluck on the security team ;)

Comment: @onecomileman - for example I show x and y axis of mouse then, how to update in template? any demo

Answer (score 1):

So here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/prabhat-angular-tooltip) project to demonstrate creating the dynamic tooltip component.

I have one tooltip directive `myTooltip` which is responsible to create a dynamic tooltip component on hover and remove on the mouse leave event.

```
  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
              private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
     this.factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TooltipComponent);
  }

  @HostListener('focusin')
  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  show(): void {
    this.tooltipComp = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.factory);
    this.tooltipComp.instance.content = this.tooltipContent;
  }

  @HostListener('focusout')
  @HostListener('mouseleave')
  @HostListener('DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument')
  hide(): void {
    this.tooltipComp && this.tooltipComp.destroy();
  }
```

Then I have a tooltip component, which accepts a `content` variable (value can be passed from the host component). So technically you can pass anything to your tooltip component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-tooltip',
  templateUrl: './tooltip.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './tooltip.component.css' ]
})
export class TooltipComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  content: any;
}
```

And finally, use it like this.

```
<div myTooltip tooltipContent='Hello There!'>
   Hover on me
</div>
```

Of course, you will have to implement the tooltip directions and CSS logic on top of it on your own.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/prabhat-angular-tooltip